# Adobe Air Questions/Resources

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, flash, air, adobe

I recently became quite interested in developing an adobe air application, and just had a few questions that maybe some more experienced air developers could answer.

Firstly, what is the average time-frame required for an air project. Mainly I'm planning a somewhat ambitious project of porting a specific forum framework over to an air app. How long would you estimate this would take me to do personally? I want something more than just the standard browser inside an app, more along the lines of built in controls/features for all the standard functionality.

Secondly, can apps be done completely with javascript/html/xml? I'm quite proficient with these 3 technologies, but have no real experience with flex/flash. This includes making the chrome as well. Do specific features require specific languages to be involved?

Finally, any good books/articles you would recommend? Preferably more advanced books/resources that lay the groundwork for making professional quality applications.

Any additional tips or insights on what you think may be useful are very much welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Start reading Adobe AIR for AJAX Developers](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/develop/ajax/), particularly the [Getting Started section](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/ajax/getting_started.html)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your skill level how would we know how long it will take you personally?

I have built and released apps in one week in my spare time, doesn't mean your project or your skillset for this project will be comparable.

Adobe Air development is fast and easy in general.

Don't reinvent the wheel making button and menu classes, leverage what's already out there.

Take a look at MadComponents: http://code.google.com/p/mad-components/ for UI

Other than that there are several robust tweening and graphics libraries out there.

There's also stage3d and frameworks to support 2d and 3d development for almost near native performance.

Answer (score -1):

You can find a python script that will do it here:

http://code.google.com/p/flashcommand/

More info here:

http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2008/05/02/flashcommand-for-os-x-updated-to-work-with-flash-cs3/

Basically, this just uses the JSFL API in Flash Pro to automate the compilation from the command line. However, it requires that Flash Pro be installed (and the script will launch it).

There is no a way to compile FLAs without using Flash Pro.

mike chambers